# mail order raspberry plants, now what

Tags: raspberries

I ordered 4 raspberry plants from burpee and they came today.  I was expecting just bare roots and a bare cane, but instead they came as a single stem with leaves and the roots in a ball of dirt.  Just a single stem maybe 8 inches tall with 10ish leaves each.  Is this considered a bare root plant?

How should i plant them so they start building roots this fall and winter?  Should i cut the stem leaving no leaves?  I want to put them in the ground in the next couple of days, should i let them get some sun before then?  Any other advice?  I live in Baltimore Maryland.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plant them so that the top of the root ball is level with the surface of the soil, pretty much as you would any other potted plant.  Water them well between now and when cold weather arrives and they will do fine.  I would get them in the ground as soon as you can because, unlike bare root plants, they are not dormant right now.

As for other advice...some raspberry varieties spread quite vigorously from underground runners.  If you have a variety like this you may want to contain them as best you can.  As they mature you will want to prune out the old canes to keep the plant healthy and productive.  Lots of information on the web about how and when to do that.

Comment: Thanks,  at any point this fall/ winter should I cut the one cane that is there (which currently has some leaves).  Right now it might be 8 inches with 10 leaves.